# Implementing a custom indicator with ViewPageIndicator - How can I do it to a gallery?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm working on a project and I managed to get to the point where I can show my images in a gallery sort of style using PagerAdapter. Now what I want to do is add an indicator to which image is on the screen and I figure that VPI could help me out - the problem is that I'm really new to code and don't know how to implement it, could someone help?

Here's a gif of what I want to achieve - the green line indicator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL8FR.jpg

I made a simpler version of my project to fit in this post, here it is:

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.exp.viewpagersstest1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context ssContext;

    private int[] ssImages = new int[] { R.drawable.splash1,R.drawable.splash2, R.drawable.splash3 };

    ImageAdapter(Context ssContext) {
        this.ssContext = ssContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ssImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View ssView, Object ssObject) {
        return ssView == ((ImageView) ssObject);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup ssContainer, int ssPosition) {
        ImageView ssImageView = new ImageView(ssContext);
        ssImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        ssImageView.setImageResource(ssImages[ssPosition]);
        ((ViewPager) ssContainer).addView(ssImageView, 0);
        return ssImageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup ssContainer, int ssPosition,
            Object ssObject) {
        ((ViewPager) ssContainer).removeView((ImageView) ssObject);
    }

}
```

SSTest.java

```
package com.exp.viewpagersstest1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class SSTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sstest);

        ViewPager ssViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ss_view_pager);
        ImageAdapter ssAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        ssViewPager.setAdapter(ssAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sstest, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

activity_sstest.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SSTest" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/ss_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ViewPagerSSTest1 Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exp.viewpagersstest1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.exp.viewpagersstest1.SSTest"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"
             >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 0):

Was much more simple than I expected, just needed to add the following to my xml:

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.UnderlinePageIndicator 
    android:id="@+id/pageIndic"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:selectedColor="#ef4154"/>
```

And the following to the oncreate under the java file:

```
UnderlinePageIndicator pageIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.pageIndic);
pageIndicator.setViewPager(ssViewPager);
```